# iPhone 5 landscape orientation triggers media query of iPhone 6

Tags: css, media-queries

My media Query for iPhone 5 Landscape mode doesn't work. It triggers the media query of iPhone 6 instead of iPhone 5. The portrait mode works perfect though. 
Following are the queries for iPhone 5

```
/* iPhone 5 (landscape) */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 568px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait) */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 568px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
}
```

I tried using the max-device-width and min-device-width also. I do have 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` included in the HTML.

Using the (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) or (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) is not working and is also messing up the portrait mode as well.

I've been trying to fix this and would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct width/height?

Comment: When your phone is in landscape ratio, what was the phone's width becomes the browser height. Instead of using `min-width: 320` and `max-width: 568` you should be either using `min/max-height` for those values on the landscape query, or using height measurements for `min/max-width`.

Comment: @ProEvilz yes. I am using a chrome extension "mobile/RWD Tester" to test the responsiveness. Do you think it works on actual iphone 5 device??

Comment: @JonUleis I tried this as well. no luck :(